# Use of contains() in sql server

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

I am having a table name `Product` contains 3 columns as:

```
Product-id
name
Price
```

In `name` column, all product names are present.

Example: 1340 GPS,  1340T GPS etc.

When I write

```
select top 10 * from product where contains(name,'1340');
```

Result 1 row `1340 GPS`

but when I search

```
select top 10 * from product where name like '%1340%';
```

Then the result is `1340 GPS and 1340T GPS`.

Actually my requirement is I will use `contains()` but it has to show both the rows like `LIKE` operator.

How to do so :?

Please help

Thanks in advance

Comment: why do you insist using `contains()` ?

Comment: i need full text search

Comment: is there any way to solve above issue or its impossible???????

Comment: the above query i am using to searching a product. If i use like operator it will take more time then contains() and also i need full text search.So i need Contains() my point of view.

Comment: I am using number of inner and other joins in my query. Is there any other way to solve this one then welcome

Comment: @user1926138 1340 come always in prefix or it can come in suffix or anywhere

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here is straight way to do this . you can use "*" before in contain syntax same as like operator . but you need to use double quote before and after the search string . check following query :

```
SELECT *
FROM product
WHERE CONTAINS(name,'"*1340*"');
```

it will definitely work .

Comment: Not need to use * in full text search.

Comment: Just a note: You can't do a prefix of * with Contains. It only works in this example because 1340 is the start of the word. If it was T1340 for instance, this wouldn't work.

Comment: its not working , its show no record when use contains()

Answer (score 2):

select * from product where FREETEXT (product.*,'"1340*"')