# How to do a SQL partial search using CONTAINS

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm new to SQL and I'm trying to perform a partial search using CONTAINS which uses a variable. It works fine when looking for a "complete" term but not partial. Let's say there's a row with the entry "Tristan" nothing pops up when I'm using just "Trist". I tried to do this: `@Word+'*'`, but it's not working. Below the code of my stored procedure.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spSearchWord]
@Word nvarchar(100)

AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

SELECT *
FROM [testDatabase].[dbo].[User]
WHERE CONTAINS (*, @Word)

END
```

Comment: Does your table have one or more columns with a full text index? Asking, since we don't have a table schema to look at.

Comment: The table has 3 columns with a full text index.

Comment: I guess if you're always going to be using a wildcard for that query, before running it, you should do: `set @word = '"' + @word + '*"';` See: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142492(SQL.90).aspx and note that the function contains will strictly only take a variable (so you can't put @word + '*' in there, even if that was the way to do it).

Comment: @ZLK Post that as an answer and I'll give you credit. Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Important note for others:

CONTAINS is a predicate used in the WHERE clause of a Transact-SQL SELECT statement to perform SQL Server full-text search on **full-text indexed columns** containing character-based data types

To directly answer the question I found this:

[Use of contains() in sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17102457/use-of-contains-in-sql-server)

In combination with ZLK's comment:

```
@variable = @variable + '*';

SELECT *
FROM user
WHERE CONTAINS(column, @variable);
```

This * syntax is similar to LIKE ('value%')

It only works from the beginning of a word with wild card on the end.  You cannot prefix with a wildcard, it is the nature of FULL-TEXT Indexing...wild cards cannot be indexed.

I found some interesting workarounds for the prefix during a search, but none that I would recommend.  You would get better performance from doing a LIKE('%value%') search than any of the workarounds I came across.